# Redundant transparent border while exporting PNG sequence

Tags: flash, export, flash-cs5, flash-cs6, jsfl

I try to export movie clips into PNG sequence using Flash CS6. Movie clips contain other movie clips. So, result PNG images contain strange redundant transperent border. As I figured out it appears when inner movie clip(or any other object) is rotated.

Here is an expample:

[image]

I export MovieClip #2 and blue rectange is PNG size. Red rectange is desirable size. I can break apart inner MovieClip but I will lose some animation. Is there any method to export PNG sequence without this border?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am understanding it like this: you've exported out a lot of pngs based off a movieclip and the result is that all of the png files are the same size as the movieclip, while for some of the png files this leaves a border of unused area around the actual graphical contents of the png.

What you want done is to have all the png dimensions be tightly wrapped to the graphical content of the pngs, even if that would mean all the pngs would have different dimensions?

If so, one way is that you could just put them through a quick pass in photoshop: Open a png in photoshop, go to Image -> Trim, then save it. You can make a quick script and just let it batch process on all your pngs to trim them.

(I don't mean to sound condensing in any way, it just sounded like an odd request to me, so I wanted to be sure.)

Comment: Unfortunately, trim will not help. It will destroy animation (because every frame will lose right position). The problem is in senseless rectangular bounds of MovieClips. They are really senseless in exporting not vector images.